# How to bind web service response (XML) to a grid using ExtJs method

Tags: javascript, web-services, extjs

I have created a sample web service which returns an xml as shown below.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public XmlDocument GetPeople()
{    
 return Factory.GetPeopleController().GetPeople(); //Returning an an xml
}
```

And I am calling webservice method as below

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.require([
  'Ext.data.*',
  'Ext.grid.*'
  ]);
    debugger

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.define('Person', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: 'xml'
            },
            fields: [
            // set up the fields mapping into the xml doc
            // The first needs mapping, the others are very basic
        'Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate']
        });
        debugger
        // create the Data Store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Person',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                // load using HTTP
                type: 'ajax',
                url: "Service.asmx/GetPeopleXml",
                // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    // records will have an "Item" tag
                    record: 'Person',
                    idProperty: 'Id'

                }
            }
        });

        // create the grid
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            columns: [
        { text: "Id", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Id' },
        { text: "FirstName", width: 180, dataIndex: 'FirstName' },
        { text: "LastName", width: 115, dataIndex: 'LastName' },
        { text: "BirthDate", width: 100, dataIndex: 'BirthDate' }
    ],
            renderTo: 'example-grid',
            width: 540,
            height: 200
        });
    });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Receiving xml from service:
     
     
      
       1
       John
       Doe
       05-03-1980
      
      
        2
        Michael
        Crowd
        12-05-1975

And I am calling this service method in a webpage using `extjs`.

I am not able to get the result. So please suggest me how to bind the xml result to grid.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's an example in the SDK download `xml-grid` that shows how to load a remote grid with XML data. Follow that.

Comment: Thanks Evan for your reply. I tried that sample and it's working fine with static xml doucment. But whenever i call webservice request in that example then its failing. Could you please check my code and tell me where is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks nothing like the example code.

Comment: Sorry Evan. Actually i didn't update the code in Stack. Can you please check now once.